# AWS DMS: Data not getting replicated to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-redshift, aws-dms

My source DB is AWS RDS and my target table is AWS Redshift. The data is loaded successfully but after that changes are not pushed to the target DB and there are no exceptions.

Configuration:
Migration type: Full Load, Ongoing Replication
Source DB: AWS RDS MariaDB
Target DB: AWS Redshit

Issue: After first upload there are no inserts, updates, deletes to the target DB.

Update: I restarted the DMS task, it duplicated the database records on target DB but now it is updating the target DB.
I drop and reloaded one table and it duplicated the record.

Comment: Don't restart, use start even if you want to update

Comment: What is the best way of fixing this issue now? :( Drop and reload of table is not working for us.

Comment: did it work?, not sure!, I'm doing S3 to Redshift

Comment: I think ShellCommandActivity can be used to the updates after first full load is done

Comment: No drop and reload of a table, duplicated the records

Comment: why don't you create two separate tasks, one for full load with "migrate existing data" and one for updating with "replicate data changes only"?

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus for your responses

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was, I updated the Redshift Database name and that somehow created problems with my AWS DMS tasks.

Creating a fresh task worked for me.